# Fedora 15 address collision on Compaq CQ41?

Tags: fedora, kernel, laptop, acpi

I keep getting an address collision warning at boot time, between ACPI and Video Rom. If I add `acpi=off` to `grub.conf` the error goes away, but then I have no power management (battery icon, proper shutdown, etc.). Anyone know the cause or a possible solution?

Comment: Does anything actually not work or is it just a boot time warning and then everything works?

Comment: @Caleb, just a warning and everything works so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be solved in BIOS configuration. If there is a newer BIOS for your machine, you should use it.

Other than that, try booting with `pci=noacpi` option. If this results in loosing some capabilities you desire, whereas presently everything works fine despite the acpi warning, you might just disable kernel warnings using **`loglevel=3`** boot option. Note however, that this disables *all* kernel warnings, so if you run into problems in the future, you might need to disable this option for diagnosing those.